# Is there a more precise approach to generate signatures for ClamAV, than regex signatures?

Tags: antivirus, scan, library

Actually I generate signatures from libraries, to scan executables for beeing statically linked to that library. My actual approach is to read out the .text section and generate a byte sequence for every function with placeholders.

For little version steps of the library there are many false positives with the clamscan from ClamAV.

Is there a better approach, to generate signatures for libraries and detect with ClamAV afterwards?

Comment: What are you currently using to write your signatures? (just by sequence? yara? ioc? )

Comment: I wrote a script reading the byte-sequences out of the .text section of the static library with some placeholders. I could not find a different approach for my task. I followed the approach described in the paper "Automatically Mining Program Build Information via Signature Matching"

Answer (score 4):

It seems that ClamAV supports both [YARA](http://blog.clamav.net/2015/06/clamav-099b-meets-yara.html)  and [OpenIOC](http://blog.clamav.net/2014/05/clamav-0983-has-been-released.html). These two methods of writing signatures will let you take a much more specific look rather than just byte sequences. Check out this [SANS paper](https://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/forensics/ioc-indicators-compromise-malware-forensics-34200) for a bit of methodology.

If you want just a quick idea of what these two frameworks can hone in on check out the documentation for [YARA](https://yara.readthedocs.org/en/v3.4.0/writingrules.html) and [IOC](http://openioc.org/terms/Common.iocterms). Both of these frameworks have a lot more documentation on how to write good signatures that will be good further reading material.

Comment: The tool of interest for OpenIOC would be IOC editor, but this one is not compatible with linux OS

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to develop signatures would be using the MD5 hash of the file using the SIGTOOL that was provided by ClamAV, but constraint here would be it would match or fire only when the hash matches with the signature.

We can also divide the hexadecimal and header section into two seperate files in order to create MD5 hash for them.

Comment: hashes are no option, because I create a signature from a library and want to match a binary linked to the library  against the signature. When I use hashes I get zero matches.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use debug and leave files:

```
clamscan --debug 2>debug.log --leave-temps --tempdir=tmp
```

You can then find useful debug code in `debug.log`.

Current `signatures.pdf`: [on GitHub](https://github.com/vrtadmin/clamav-devel/blob/07e80411dc2b05565923e00bc844b66bb2dd2813/docs/signatures.pdf)

Comment: Hi, welcome on InfoSec. I noticed that you added two answers to one question. It is essentially better to post one, complete answer. You can always edit your posts, so if you forget to add something, you can add it later. Our [help center](https://security.stackexchange.com/help) can give you some guidiance on how to write great answers.